# Is there a way to fully qualify the use of a VBA function?

Tags: excel, vba

So I just learned that if you type VBA. this will activate an auto list that includes VBA functions. Does this mean that VBA is an object? If I want to "fully qualify" using a VBA function, what would those qualifiers be?

For example, would these all be valid statements:

```
x = Sqr(25)
x = VBA.Sqr(25)
x = Application.VBA.Sqr(25)
```

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No, the last one is not valid as the `Application` object doesn't have a VBA property (wouldn't make any sense).

Comment: A library is always going to be the top level. If you open the object browser (F2), they'll be in the libraries drop-down in the upper left hand corner.

Comment: There are also some other "features".  For example, `Array(a,b,c)` respects the `Option Base` statement, whereas `VBA.Array(a,b,c)` will always result in a `Base 0` array.

Comment: Appreciate the responses! To clarify: VBA is a library but not an object? Or it's an object that is of type library?

Comment: VBA is a library, as is Excel. `Excel.Application` would be the object.

Comment: Does that mean Excel.VBA is the object?

Comment: No, Excel and VBA are different libraries. VBA doesn't have an object - it's more like a namespace.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't qualify, the default is that VBA assumes it is a VBA function.  If you want to use a worksheet function in VBA, then use something like:

```
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A1").Value, Range("B1:C100"), 1, False)
```

It is REALLY important to qualify if you use a function like`TRIM()` because the VBA version and the worksheet version have different results.

Comment: I just looked into how things are organized in the object browser. If I'm correct, all of these would be the same if we're qualifying a VBA function:
    x = Sqr(25)
    x = VBA.Sqr(25)
    x = VBA.Math.Sqr(25)
    x = Math.Sqr(25)

Comment: @GeekyFreaky  It is always useful to experiment and see what forms the compiler will accept and the quality of the results produced.

Comment: Yes, I did that and it accepted all of them, but just wanted to make sure! :)